# How to avoid loading wrong libraries when using a subprocess.Popen() from a python script to run a venv?

Tags: python, subprocess, loadlibrary

I want to run a script using a venv python~3.9 from a subprocess call of another application that uses python3.6. However the imported libraries are wrong and from the site-packages of 3.6 version. How can I modify the subprocess call to load the correct libraries i.e from the venv(3.9 version)

```
p = Popen([process_name, parameters_l], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

I have tried using the cwd and also changing the working directory via os.chdir however that doesn't seem to work. Furthermore I tried to run activat.bat from the venv, but the issue persists.

Comment: Would you type `which python` in your shell(or terminal)? post it here, please.

Comment: So ofcourse the python call is for 3.9, i.e sys.executable print is: D:/Test/python/venv/Scripts/python.exe.                                                           However it fails to load the libraries correctly:                                                            
File "D:\Core\build\Slicer\lib\Python\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__config__.py", line 13, in <module>
    os.add_dll_directory(extra_dll_dir)
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory'

Comment: @Srijeet Are you trying to run a 3D Slicer app?

Comment: @mx0,  Yes I am trying to a python script from the 3D slicer python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve the issue I had to get the current environment and delete some variables e.g:

```
env = os.environ.copy()
del env["PYTHONPATH"]

Popen([process_name, parameters_l], env=env)
```

Finally use the new env in the subprocess call as a parameter. Hope it helps if anyone is facing a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

This is my example.

## example.py

this code show python version you run.

```
import sys 
print("version {}".format(sys.version))
```

## traverse_python.sh

this code traverses various python versions to show what version runs the code.

you can change the `process_name` to the python version you want to use.

```
import time
import subprocess, os

pythoninterpretor = ['/usr/local/bin/python3.10', '/usr/local/bin/python3.11']

for i in pythoninterpretor:
    process_name = i
    parameters = 'example.py'
    p = subprocess.Popen([process_name, parameters])
    time.sleep(10)
```

## my results

FYI, the result won't change even if you explicitly use another python version in shebang in the script.

```
version 3.10.8 (main, Oct 13 2022, 10:17:43) [Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)]
version 3.11.0 (main, Oct 25 2022, 14:13:24) [Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)]
```

In your case,

```
python_interpretor = '/absolute/path/env/python3.9'
p = Popen([python_interpretor, process_name, parameters_l], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

and you need to replace `/absolute/path/env/python3.9` with your ideal version's path.